# Memory leak when std::string size >= 16

Tags: c++

I'm getting a memory leak reported for this incomplete test case. If I pass "nameNameNameNam" instead then there is no report of a leak.

```
TEST_F (TestDoesExist, namePassedToCInterface)
{
    Accessor accessor(_cInterface, _handle);
    accessor.doesExist(std::string("nameNameNameName"));
}
```

The code under test looks like this:

```
virtual bool doesExist(const std::string& name) 
{
    bool result;
    _cInterface.exists(_txHandle, name.c_str(), &result);
    return result;
}
```

The call to the C interface is mocked as follows:

```
class MockDoesExist
{
public:
    MockDoesExist() {
        handle=Handle();
        name = "";
        result = true;
    }

    static void func(Handle _handle, const char* _name, bool* _result) {
        // in values
        handle = _handle;
        name = _name;

        // out values
        *_result = result;
    }

    // in values
    static Handle handle;
    static std::string name;
    // out values
    static bool result;
};
Handle MockDoesExist::handle;
std::string MockDoesExist::name;
bool MockDoesExist::result;
```

I'm comiling with VS 2010 express.

I have:

```
_CrtMemCheckpoint( &memAtStart );
```

before the testcase execution and:

```
_CrtMemDifference( &memDiff, &memAtStart, &memAtEnd)
```

after.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The 15 character limit is probably due to "small string optimization" in the std::string class (for small strings the data is stored in a member array, without allocating anything dynamically).

Comment: One possible trick is to run your tests three times, and treat reported allocations that don't come in a multiple of 3 as low-priority for investigation (since it's probably not a persistent leak). A possible fix is to tediously clean up your static variables prior to calling `_CrtMemDifference`. For example, `std::string().swap(MockDoesExist::name);`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing. The `_CrtMemDifference` is called after the test case, but *before* the static members of `MockDoesExist` get destroyed (they get destroyed just before program termination). During your test case, `MockDoesExist::name` gets assigned your long string. In MSVC's standard library there is a optimization for short strings, meaning each std::string has an internal 16 byte char array where shorter strings may be stored. Only for longer strings it has to allocate memory from the free store. That memory will be released in the string's destructor, in this case when `MockDoesExist::name` gets destroyed, i.e. after `_CrtMemDifference` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. Once `MockDoesExist::name` get destroyed, the reported "memory leak" will disappear.